# Disable ESXi passthrough on SATA controller

Tags: vmware-esxi, sata, passthrough, intel-vt-x

I have a newly built ESXi server with two SSD's hooked up to the motherboard primary SATA controller.  Everything was working until I made the mistake of enabling passthrough on that SATA controller.  Now, ESXi will reboot & come up complaining it doesn't have any data stores configured:

[image]

Each time I'll go in & uncheck passthrough for that controller & reboot again, but it keeps coming back up enabled.  Not sure what to do from here?

I tried temporarily disabling VT-d in BIOS, but that didn't help.  Passthrough showed disabled in ESXi, but I still got the persistent storage error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just reinstall, which would reset the configuration.

Comment: Probably what I'll have to do.

Comment: I re-installed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't expect any data to still exist on the SSD drives, disable VT-D, reboot and create a new datastore in the storage tab on the SSD's. That would become your "persistent storage".

Comment: One of the SSD's is the ESXi boot disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem where I have three M.2 PCIE SSD's and enabled the wrong two for Passthrough (PCIE numbering seems to be opposite from what I thought it would be. It loses al changes after reboot, so you can't undo this anymore. Will try to boot ESXi from a USB stick, so I safely can move my VM's on that datastore to a NAS. Then I can probably reinstall ESXi and enable the right SSD's for Passthrough.